# DBUnit not able to find the dataset.xml class located in src/test/resources folder

Tags: java, xml, maven, junit, dbunit

I have a DBUnit program that is not able to find an xml file located in `src/test/resources` folder.

**Maven Folder Structure**

```
src/test/java - StateDaoTest.java
src/test/resources - dataset.xml
```

Upon compiling the project I see that both the following files in `target/test-classes` folder:

- StateDaoTest.class
- dataset.xml

This is error log I see when I run the test:

**Error Log:**

```
Running StateDaoTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.451 sec <<< FAILURE!
testGetStateByStateCode(StateDaoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.02 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dataset.xml (The specified path is invalid)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        .....
```

Can somebody please guide ?

Comment: To offer help we need to see the test code - the reference to the file, how it loads the file, etc.  The problem is probably with the file reference or how loading it.